# Python and Scrapy, and attempting to get scraped data into MariaDB/MYSQL Database

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, mariadb, mariasql

The below code is unfinished I know, but all that I am simply trying to do is get those yield results into my MARIADB.  I spent far too many hours combing Stackoverflow, looking for this answer.   The code works great and I can manually add the final items to enter stuff into a database with static information,  but I have tried everything I can in the for loop.

I just need the final lines of code to figure this out, and I am confident I can move on to finally scraping data.

```
import scrapy
import mysql.connector
from scrapy.selector import Selector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  database="database",  
  user="root",
  password="password"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO testTable (name) VALUES (%s)"

class scrapysclass(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scrapy-name"

    start_urls = ['url']

    def parse(self, response):
        quotes = str(response.xpath('//comment()').extract())
        quotes = quotes.replace('<!--','').replace('-->','')
        sel = Selector(text=quotes)
        for row in sel.xpath('//table[@id="tableid"]//tbody/tr'):
            yield {
                'first' : row.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract_first(),
                'last': row.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract_first(),
                'handle' : row.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract_first(),
            }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are establishing the connection with the DB along side the spider, you could have the cursor execute the insert query instead of yielding the item.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO testTable (name, last_name, handle) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"

...

for row in sel.xpath('//table[@id="tableid"]//tbody/tr'):
    first = row.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract_first()
    last = row.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract_first()
    handle = row.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract_first()
    
    data = (first, last, handle)
    mycursor.execute(sql, data)
```

*Notice that I've changed your sql statement, as it wasn't clear for me which data should go there.*

**I must point out that this is not the best solution for this.**

Ideally your spider should be in charge of only scraping the data, and you should write an Item Pipeline for inserting the data into the database.

When you write a pipeline, everytime the spider yield an item that it was scraped, the `process_item` method will be called to handle that item. [Here in the docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) you will find some examples of pipelines.

Comment: This is essentially the same answer I came up with on my own, but this works too.